# Cannot set system path to Header Search Paths in XCode iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

In short, in the **iOS project** I set `/usr/local/include/` to Header Search Paths, then in source code I cannot include the headers in this directory. But in the **Mac OS X projects** anything is fine. How can I modify my setting of **iOS project** correctly?

In the long detail, I created a new **iOS Cocoa Touch Framework project**. Since I wanna include some headers of boost which was installed by Homebrew, I set the Header Search Paths in build **TARGETS** (not **PROJECTS**) as `/usr/local/include/`. The code `#include <boost/noncopyable.hpp>` cannot be compiled and the message is "boost/noncopyable.hpp file not found." But in **Mac OS X projects**, it can be compiled with the same code and the same settings.

Answer (score 1):

I found out the cause of this problem, that is, the **iOS projects** don't figure out the alias directory(and file?).

The boost libraries through Homebrew were installed in

`/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.57.0/include/` (dependent)

, and Homebrew create some alias directories and files in

`/usr/local/include/`

To include heads of boost in **iOS projects**, we must set the Header Search Paths as real path, and not alias path.

However until now, i cannot figure out why behaviors are different between **iOS projects** and **Mac OS X projects**. The current version of XCode is 6.4 (6E35b).

Answer (score 0):

Select the Build Settings tab, then search for public header. Double click on the Public Headers Folder Path setting and enter the following in the popup:

Answer (score 0):

Select the Build Settings tab, then search for public header. Double click on the Public Headers Folder Path setting and enter the following in the popup:

include/$(PROJECT_NAME)